# Port Qt3Support to Qt4

Tags: qt, qt4, qt3

I may ask a stupid question: in this article [Porting from Qt 4 to Qt 5](http://www.kdab.com/porting-from-qt-4-to-qt-5/) the author mentioned "Qt3Support code is a method which has been renamed to something more appropriate in Qt 4. "

So I would like to know: does there exists a kind of list or something that we can port all qt3support methods. How could we find the correspondance of the methods in Qt4 to the Qt3Support methods? Could someone who has already done this job share some experience please?

Thanks in advance :)

PS: I found some additional information which suits as well as the best answer to my needs:
[Porting to Graphics View](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/graphicsview-porting.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Between Qt 3 and Qt 4 some properties have changed name, some have changed meanings, some have been removed, some are totally new, etc. Some classes (like `QTextEdit` and `QTextBrowser`) have a completely different API.

However, you can find some correspondences and a lot of notes here: 
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/porting4.html

I've ported some code from Qt 3 to Qt 4, but not to Q t5.

Comment: You may start from here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtdoc/portingguide.html

Comment: There is no Qt3Support in Qt5, and no need of a Qt4Support because there are no so many differencies. You should start deleting Qt3Support from Qt4 code.